# Byte to megabyte conversion difference on Windows

Tags: windows, byte, memory-size, megabyte

Why does the amount differ when I convert bytes to Megabytes?

You have to multiply the amount by 1000 000 again. I thought the conversion automatically does that for you?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work fine for me:

[image: google search result]

You may want to try it without writing any commas on the left-hand side (where you input the bytes). I believe that some locales (i.e. US English; correct me if I'm wrong) use commas as the decimal separator (like we use period in the US), which might be confusing Google's converter (it might think you typed 169 bytes plus almost one half).

Comment: ahhhhhh Ofcorse! Thank you